# Sort or update a table using order by or any other way

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to sort on a column in MS SQL. I have a table say Performance which looks like below, and my requirement is to sort it which can be done easily using order by "column name", but how do I save it permanently in sorted way, I mean I don't just want to view sorted data using select statement in fact I wanted to make permanent change to this view.

```
Marks    Roll number    Name   
44         5            Mike
22         2            Robin
44         1            Jack
34         3            a
22         4            b
```

Expected:

```
22      2          Robin
22      4          b
34      3          a
44      1          Jack
44      5          Mike
```

Comment: If you want a specific ordering, put an ORDER BY in the outer query. Period. There is no other way, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Relational databases have no concept of ordering the rows in a table. If you want ordered output, you must use an `ORDER BY` clause. This is a fundamental fact and is not something you can work around.

In SQL Server 2000, in (essentially) error, Microsoft allowed views to have an `ORDER BY` clause, which did order the output. However, in SQL Server 2005 this was changed because it was never really right to operate that way.

You could try the `SELECT TOP (2147483647) * FROM dbo.Blah B ORDER BY B.Col;` trick, but that won't cut it in later versions of SQL Server, either. The ordering behavior of `TOP` is a side effect, not a main effect, and shouldn't be relied on in a view. Do it right and put sorting where it should be: in the presentation layer or in the final, outer query that is submitted to the database (ala `SELECT Columns FROM dbo.View ORDER BY X;`).

A little more on not ordering rows in a table: yes, there are clustered indexes, but you can't rely on the data returning ordered for several reasons:

- A nonclustered index may be used to satisfy the query, so the clustered index's ordering will have no impact on the output rowset's ordering.
- There may be no clustered index at all on the table.
- While each clustered index page's rows are less than the next page and greater than the previous page, the rows inside each page are not themselves ordered.
- Parallelism can change the order that rows are produced as one stream may return faster or slower than others.
- During query execution, if another process is already reading some of the rows that will satisfy the current query, that data may be borrowed for the current query *out of order* in order to save reads (after which the current query will fetch only the remaining rows it is missing).

There is one simple, reliable, and **required** way to get an ordered rowset: `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Another bullet you could add: the clustered index is not always used to satisfy a query, and thus the clustered index ordering will have no impact on the resulting order of the output. In fact of the reasons you mentioned, this is by far the simplest to demonstrate.